# Incorrect UPDATE syntax near '='

Tags: sql, vb.net

I got some error "incorrect syntax near '='" in update.

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    conn.Open()
    For i = 0 To Me.Dgv_sql.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim idx As String = Dgv_sql.Rows(i).Cells("ID").Value
        query = "UPDATE kkpsurabaya SET late = '" & Dgv_sql.Rows(i).Cells("late").Value & "' WHERE ID = " & idx

        If (UpdateData(query)) Then

        End If

    Next
    conn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Data Berhasil Di Update", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    'dgv_sql_isi()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Print to console the variables being used in the query along with the resulting query (before execution), and post the result here.

Comment: Are you sure the idx exists and is assigned to the code well ? Please place breakpoint on line where you execute the query and look at the command itself

Comment: First step in debugging such a sql statement: what is the *real* statement that is executed? Maybe there is a value (containing quotes) that breaks your statement, or you need extra quotes. So the second step is: replace all values with parameters - then all sorts of problems go away..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Idx` is a string so when you just do `where ID = (and place string here)` it'll fail.

Change to:

```
query = "UPDATE kkpsurabaya SET late = '" & Dgv_sql.Rows(i).Cells("late").Value & "' WHERE ID = '" & idx &"'"
```

But a better solution will just be to use [Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) all together.. - Will help you avoid [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: `idx` is a string, but is the `id` a (n)varchar? The question doesn't say.

Comment: True but I don't think it matters if `id` is a (n)varchar or not. It fails because of the lack of `''`. If it was because of the type it would have been a different error

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable and assign the value to that variable first.

```
vara=Dgv_sql.Rows(i).Cells("late").Value
query = "UPDATE kkpsurabaya SET late = '" & vara & "' WHERE ID = " & idx
```

Hope it will help.